# Using sleep() function as timer with while loop is not working?

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, sleep

I want a `while` loop to `echo` the value of `x` every 5 seconds, until `x` is equal to 10, but using the `sleep()` function makes it `echo` all 10 values at the end of the loop, rather than one at a time every 5 seconds.

```
$x = 1;
while($x <= 10) {
  sleep(5);
  echo $x;
  $x++;
}
```

How do I get around this issue without having to use cron?

P.S. I need to run the script via web server, not console.

Comment: Do you run this script in console, or via web server?

Comment: @nikserg web server.

Answer (score 0):

It's expected behavior. Web-server does not send output to user as soon as it appears. Output will be sent to user, when script finish, not earlier. `sleep()` just makes script to run longer.
If you need make some webpage, where lines appear dynamically, you need to use JavaScript. It's front-end task, not back-end.

Comment: Actually I need to send curl requests every 10 seconds, that is the purpose of this loop with sleep(). I reckon sending http requests via javascript won't be possible, so I have to do this via PHP. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is a delay in the output reaching your browser, not a delay in the PHP code. By default, web servers will "buffer" output, sending the browser a chunk at a time rather than every byte individually.

You can change that (using `flush()` and `ob_flush`) but it sounds like that's not actually what you're trying to achieve. To make your experiment clearer, try echoing the time at each step:

```
$x = 1;
while($x <= 10) {
  sleep(5);
  echo (new DateTime)->format('H:i:s'), "<br>\n';
  $x++;
}
```

Although they all reach your browser at the same time, you will be able to see that the command actually ran spread out as you wanted.

Comment: Thanks that helps. I want to make curl request after every 5 seconds, FYI.